# Changing Scientific notation on Y axis of Lattice density plot in R

Tags: r, lattice

I am just learning R AND I have a fairly basic question....

Here is some sample code -

```
library(MASS)
library(lattice)
Tbirthwt <- MASS::birthwt

par(mar=c(4,6,2,2))
densityplot(~bwt , group=factor(race), data = Tbirthwt,lwd=3,xlab="Weight in 
Grams",
        auto.key=T, 
        main="Birth Weight Children by Mothers \nRace:(1=White,2=Black,3=other)")
```

The resulting plot has the Y axis in Scientific notation. How do I convert this from Scientific notation?

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.
-Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adjusting `scipen`.

```
options(scipen = 999)
```